# $H^0 (\psi_i)$ on $\mathcal M_{0;n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Thinking about moduli spaces of tropical curves, I obtained the following result:

On the moduli space of tropical marked rational curves $\mathcal M^{trop}_{0;n}$ for any $i$ we have:
$\dim H^0 (\psi_i) = 2 {n-1\choose 2} - 4$.

I was wondering, if the dimension of space of holomorphic sections is the same in the case of complex rational curves?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd be interested to even understand the result. I assume $H_{0}$ is the space of sections, but what is $\psi _{i}$?

Comment: To Piotr, it is just a $\psi$-class. The divisor corresponding to the the line bundle over $\mathcal M_{0;n}$ with the fiber given by the cotangent space to the $i$-th marked point.